# How can I get Firefox to reopen windows in the workspaces they were previously in?

Tags: gnome, firefox, workspaces

I use Firefox windows to lump together different projects I'm working on, and I use separate workspaces so that alt-tabbing doesn't cycle through all those separate projects, but just my editor, browser, and file system.

What can I do to get Firefox, on reopen, to restore the let's say 7 windows in the 7 different workspaces?

Thanks!

Ubuntu 18.04 by the way. Gnome shell.

Comment: Upvoted your question, but not as such easily possible I fear.